# How many significant figures do iOS devices calculate current location to?

Tags: ios, geolocation

When an iOS application requests the user's current location, to how many significant figures are the latitude and longitude values returned?

Just looking for the maximum no. of digits for database constraints.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There's no real answer to this. Among other reasons, the accuracy returned by CoreLocation varies and the conversion from degrees to linear distance depends on location.

At this point, I think the lowest accuracy I've seen returned by CoreLocation is 5 meters but in theory this could get better with time.

Wikipedia has [a table of conversion from degrees to linear distance at the equator](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Decimal_degrees). Six fractional digits gets you down to 10 cm at the equator which is probably higher than the phone is going to provide in the foreseeable future. Five digits gets you to 1 meter but it's not too hard to imagine a future device besting that.